# error about hashed password don't match in php

Tags: php

I am trying to login with a username or email and password in php. As i try to login it says password do not match, as i have typed the correct username and password. I guess something going wrong with my hashing password or session variable. Can anybody help me with my code?

Here is my login.inc.php file

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['Loginsubmit'])) {
  include 'dbh.inc.php';

  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
  $password= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

  // Error handlers
  if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
    exit();
  } else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= '$username' OR email= '$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($resultCheck < 1) {
      header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
      exit();
    } else {
      if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // De-hashing the password
        $hashedPasswordCheck = password_verify($password, $row['password']);
        if ($hashedPasswordCheck == false) {
          header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
          exit();
        } elseif ($hashedPasswordCheck == true) {
           // Log in the user here
          $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
          $_SESSION['surname'] = $row['surname'];
          $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
          $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
          $_SESSION['bdate'] = $row['bdate'];
          $_SESSION['gender'] = $row['gender'];
          header("Location: ../home.php");
          exit();
        }
      }
    }
  }
} else {
  header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
  exit();
}
```

And here is my part of index.php file where i am taking the inputs

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Mysite</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
  <link href="css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrapValidator.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/465fa6787a.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- logo -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNav">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">BRAND</a>
        </div>
      <!-- menu items -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNav">
        <div class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
              </span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
          <div class="input-group ">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
              </span>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="Loginsubmit">Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: check for errors, you have some, obvious ones.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says **[you may be at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)**. Learn about [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4712113/5827005). I recommend `PDO`, which I [wrote a class for](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO) to make it extremely easy, clean, and more secure than using non-parameterized queries. Also, [This article](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison) may help you choose between `MySQLi` and `PDO`

Comment: `$password= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);` Just pass the raw password

Comment: @Machavity I can’t pass the raw password as it will be login for the different users. Any idea what is going wrong in the code?

Comment: You need to pass the raw password to `password_verify`. Don't try to encode it first